# Domain is not resolving on AWS.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am using EC2 Amazon Web services, and also I am using route 53. My domain example.com is not resolving, I can see the website if I type elastic IP address. How can I solve this problem. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

A very nicely written steps to do the config :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-configure-route53.html

Comment: The thing is I dont see anything on alias target. That is the problem i think

Comment: I did ,now works fine..bu when I saved to records following message appears: Tried to create an alias that targets name.com., type A in zone ZNENHUHMGMFOB, but that target was not found ...Is that fine?

Comment: You should not use a alias target. An alias target can point to a cloudfront distribution, a ELB, a static web site built by S3 bucket or another Route 53 resource recordset in the same hosted zone. I don't think it applies to your case.

Comment: i think, I should close AWS account and get classic hosting, it is enough complicated.

Comment: I don't mean to discourage you. Did you add the type A record pointing to your EIP? It is still not working?

Comment: I think I did ..name : my domain, type: A , Value: EIP

Comment: now it works, but when I type the address www.mydomain.com not resolving

Comment: To make www.mydomain.com work, you need to add the cname entry

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not add what you have done so far in the route 53, I have to ask below general question and you can verify if you have done these.

1. Have you created a hosted zone?
2. Have you added type A record in your recordset to point example.com to your EIP?
3. Have you created cname for your www.example.com?
4. Have you logged in your domain name registrar site and updated the nameservers provided by route 53?

Comment: 1- yes i did 2- I missed to do this and i did now like www.domain.com.
type A, EIP (elactic IP) .. Is that right

Comment: Yes and you need to do step 4 too.

Comment: what is the step 4? now I can browse all website under domain.com, but www.domain.com no

Comment: I did, I made a record type A www.domain.com alias with domain.com..It works fine..great thanks to all.